# Jsoup recove text from div without selector

Tags: java, jsoup

I have this HTML code

```
<div itemprop="doseSchedule">
text1
</div>
<h3><a id="SP3">TITLE</a></h3>
<div>text2</div>
<div itemprop="warning">
text3
</div>
```

and I try to recover text2, but can't still. How I can do it?

Comment: what code have you tried so far?

Comment: @TomMac I have solved with this code:
   for (Element element : select) {
     String testo = element.text();
     if (testo.contains("04.3")) {
      String substring = getPrecauzioni(testo);
      parafarmaco.setPrecauzioni(substring.trim());
     }

     if (testo.contains("06.0")) {
      String substring = getCodiceGMP(testo);
      parafarmaco.setCodiceGMP(substring.trim());
     }
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do what you want:

```
public class JSoupTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String html = "<div itemprop=\"doseSchedule\">\n"
            + "text1\n"
            + "</div>\n"
            + "<h3><a id=\"SP3\">TITLE</a></h3>\n"
            + "<div>text2</div>\n"
            + "<div itemprop=\"warning\">\n"
            + "text3\n"
            + "</div>";

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    Element e = doc.select("h3").first().nextElementSibling();

    System.out.println(e.text());
    }
}
```